# Why is ESM throwing a syntax error in react backend?

Tags: reactjs, import, syntax-error, es6-modules

I'm using esm to enable the use of import/export syntax in the backend of a react project instead of require, but despite this I'm now getting the error

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

My code in index.js:

```
require = require("esm")(module);

import userRoutes from './user';
```

And the error I'm getting when running `node index.js`:

> (node:18560) Warning: To load an ES module, set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
> C:\Users\haval\dev\online-shop\gocodeshop-server\index.js:5
> import userRoutes from './user';
>
> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

(I have installed esm using **npm i esm**).

Is there any reason that esm isn't picking up the import?

Comment: Have you tried this? `set "type": "module" in the package.json or use the .mjs extension.`

Comment: No, I don't have "type": "module" in the package.json since I use the require syntax in some other parts of the backend - could this be a problem?  And shouId I change the .js extension to .mjs in both files (including index.js) or only user.js?

Comment: i checked the npm README of esm. https://www.npmjs.com/package/esm  looks like you are missing the second one. module.exports = require("./main.js")

Comment: I tried adding **module.exports = require("./routes/user");**    after the **require("esm")(module)** (I don't have a main.js, I'm calling this inside index.js) but still get the same error

Comment: how are you running the project...u have to run using node -r esm **your_file.js** by the way, is it a nodejs project you are mentioning and not react? it's for nodejs right?

Answer (score 0):

```js
//Check the order of import. 

import userRoutes from './user';

const requiredModule = require("esm")(module);
```